# Excel to WhatsApp sending text message

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, whatsapp

I am using the below code to send text messages from Excel (ver. 2019 / Windows 10)

Series of excel formulas generate WhatsApp link at R2 cell (eg.: `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=911234567809&text=ABCDEFGH`)

```
Sub send_msg()

Range("R2").Activate
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="" & ActiveCell.Value
Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)
SendKeys "~"

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Loop
End

End Sub
```

While executing the above code I am facing the below problems

1. few messages are not delivering i.e. skipping to the next number (even all the numbers were saved in WhatsApp contacts)
2. every time the code opens a new tab of Whatsapp web instead of using the already opened WhatsApp web tab (Edge is the default web browser and WhatsApp desktop also installed)

How can I fix the above two problems

Thanks in advance

Comment: "few messages are not delivering" > try to put some delay between the send. | "every time the code opens a new tab " > insert a command to close window/tab every time after send.

Comment: Added ```Application.SendKeys "^{W}", True``` to the new tab.....

Comment: Messages are skipping even after adding some delay. Messages are delivering alternatively i.e. R3, R5, R7 like. Any solution for this.

Comment: If "delivering alternatively" is consistent, just insert a dummy number (in excel) in between should do. (just imho)

Comment: File contains nearly 3500 to 4000 rows

Comment: rather than " insert a dummy number (in excel) " .. you wanna try to " insert a dummy loop skip (in vba) " ?